# Run WinSCP script via Task Scheduler

Tags: scheduled-tasks, winscp

I have written a script to open a session WinSCP via task scheduler. My code is:

```
open ftpes://user:password @192.168.88.200:3688/
```

In Task Scheduler, I execute it by specifying:

- Program/scripts: `C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe`
- on Add argument: `D:\test.txt`

When I trying to execute it, WinSCP opens and shows:

> Host 'D' Does not exist.

I saved on script on disk D. Can you help me please with what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run WinSCP script, use [`/script=` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#scripting), for example:

- Program/script: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com"`
- Add arguments: `/script="D:\test.txt"`

Resources:

- [Guide to scripting with WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation);
- [Guide to scheduling file transfers with WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule).

You can also have [WinSCP GUI generate both the script and batch file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#script) for you (or even a batch file that directly contains the WinSCP commands).